# Cannot save modifications made in xlsx file

Tags: python, xlsx, minidom

I read a .xlsx file, update it but Im not able to save it

```
from xml.dom import minidom as md
        [... some code ....]
        sheet = workDir + '/xl/worksheets/sheet'
        sheet1 = sheet + '1.xml'
        importSheet1 = open(sheet1,'r')
        whole_file= importSheet1.read()
        data_Sheet = md.parseString(whole_file)
        [... some code ....]
            self.array_mem_name = []
            y = 1
            x = 5 #first useful row
            day = int(day)
            found = 0
            while x <= len_array_shared:
                readrow = data_Sheet.getElementsByTagName('row')[x]
                c_data = readrow.getElementsByTagName('c')[0]
                c_attrib = c_data.getAttribute('t')
                if c_attrib == 's':
                    vName = c_data.getElementsByTagName('v')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                    #if int(vName) != broken:
                    mem_name = self.array_shared[int(vName)]
                    if mem_name != '-----':
                        if mem_name == old:
                            c_data = readrow.getElementsByTagName('c')[day]
                            c_attrib = c_data.getAttribute('t')
                            if (c_attrib == 's'):
                                v_Attrib = c_data.getElementsByTagName('v')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                                if v_Attrib != '':
                                    #loc = self.array_shared[int(v_Attrib)]
                                    index = self.array_shared.index('--')
                                    c_data.getElementsByTagName('v')[0].firstChild.nodeValue = index
    
                                    with open(sheet1, 'w') as f:
                                        f.write(whole_file)
```

As you can see I use `f.write(whole_file)` but **whole_file** has not the changes made with `index`.
Checking the debug I see that the new value has been added to the node, but I can't save sheet1 with the modified value

Comment: seems you're trying to write excel like plain text file.

Comment: I think so, but cant find the correct way. After several tries what I got was 0 byte file or file without the modifications or error from the debugger

Comment: you're trying to edit the open xml format directly? that could require too much effort. try library such as `openpyxl` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using openpyxl instead, as was suggested in [a comment by Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271119/cannot-save-modifications-made-in-xlsx-file/68272058#comment120660060_68271119). I found that this tool worked better for my jobs. With openpyxl, reading cell values is much easier than with `xml.dom.minidom`.

My only concern is that openpyxl seems really slower than the dom to load the workbook. Maybe the memory was overloaded. But, I was more interested in using something simpler than this minor performance issue.